# Call string method on string literal

Tags: lua

If I have a variable of string type, I can use the `:` syntax to call functions on the string metatable:

```lua
local s = "%d"
print(s:format(s:byte(1)))  -- 37
```

But this doesn't work for string literals:

```lua
print("%d":format("%d":byte(1)))
-- ')' expected near ':'
```

Why? Is there a trick to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From section 9 of [the manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html) (*sic*):

> ## 9 – The Complete Syntax of Lua
>
> ```
> [...]
>
> var ::=  Name | prefixexp ‘[’ exp ‘]’ | prefixexp ‘.’ Name
>
> [...]
>
> prefixexp ::= var | functioncall | ‘(’ exp ‘)’
> functioncall ::=  prefixexp args | prefixexp ‘:’ Name args
>
> [...]
> ```

Basically:

- A "method" `functioncall` is made of four parts: `prefixexp`, the colon, the name of the method, and its arguments.
- A `prefixexp` can be either a `functioncall` itself, an `exp` wrapped inside a pair of parentheses, or a `var`.
- A `var` can be an identifier, or its indexed/dotted counterpart.

This effectively disallows using the shorthand `:method` syntax on all kinds of literal expressions, not just strings. That said, these are all invalid syntax:

```lua
nil:has_no_methods()
true:or_false()
2:too()
[[long strings]]:same_thing()
function() end:really('?')
{}:h_yes_definitely('!')
```

...but this is valid:

```lua
foo:bar 'baz':qux()  -- Parsed as foo:bar('baz'):qux()
```

In conclusion, either use a variable, or just wrap your literal value in parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

Surround the literal with parentheses:

```lua
print(("%d"):format(("%d"):byte(1)))
```